# SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in Discord.js v12

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I've started out a new bot in Discord.js and when I try to run my index.js file, `SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` that error happens. My index.js file is as shown below... (As there is too much code, I'll have to shorten it)

```
const fs = require("fs");
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require("./config.json");

const modules = fs.readdirSync("./commands")
client.commands = new Discord.Collection()

for(const cmds of modules) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${cmds}`)
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    }

client.on('ready', () => {
    // Status Code Block
}
});


client.on('message', async message => {
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/g)
    const cmdName = args.shift()

    if(!client.commands.has(cmdName)) return

    const command = client.commands.get(cmdName)
    command.run(message, args, client)
})

client.login(token);
```

No idea what's wrong with it. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to use a good indentation logic, because it helps you spot issues like this very quickly. For instance, using emacs' indentation the error is easy to spot:

```js
client.on('ready', () => {                                                                          
  // Status Code Block                                                                              
}                                                                                                   
         });
```

Just remove the extra curly brackets to get rid of the (parse) error:

```
client.on('ready', () => {                                                                          
  // Status Code Block                                                                              
});
```

Comment: Error still here even after removing the status code

Comment: I can't reproduce that. With that error removed it parses fine in node.js.

Comment: Yeah. There's nothing wrong in that file. I got my friend to check that as well

Answer (score 0):

What I'm missing in your code up top is the client definition.

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
```

But lets assume that you have a client defined in your index file. Have you tried regenerating the token on your discord developer portal? Maybe it somehow leaked and got revoked.

Comment: That wouldn't be a `SyntaxError`.

Comment:  I totally forgot about that... Also. Still same error sadly

Comment: Sadly if it's not that then I also can't reproduce the error